# Pyenv install via git causing homebrew removal. Why?

Tags: path, zsh

#### Background:

macbook pro

chip: m1

os ver: 12.2.1 (21D62)

### Problem

I previously had homebrew installed on this machine via curl [found on homebrew's homepage].

I was having issues installing pyenv and came across [this](https://laict.medium.com/install-python-on-macos-11-m1-apple-silicon-using-pyenv-12e0729427a9) guide.

Step 1 was somewhat successful:

- pyenv got installed
- I was able to add the exports and evals to my `.zshrc` file:

```bash
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv" 
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" 
eval "$(pyenv init --path)" 
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

I noticed the following after closing and reopening iterm2:

- I was getting a `pyenv command not found` error coming from .zshrc
- The brew command was also not found
- I was still able to use the `pyenv` command, despite the initial error when opening a new terminal session.

#### Logs

My install logs (all commands taken from above link)

```bash
thleo ~ /Users/thleo  > ~  git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
Cloning into '/Users/thleo/.pyenv'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 21712, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (470/470), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (346/346), done.
remote: Total 21712 (delta 336), reused 194 (delta 107), pack-reused 21242
Receiving objects: 100% (21712/21712), 4.37 MiB | 1.17 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (14676/14676), done.
thleo ~ /Users/thleo  > ~  cd ~/.pyenv && src/configure && make -C src
gcc -fno-common     -c -o realpath.o realpath.c
gcc -dynamiclib -dynamic -undefined dynamic_lookup   -o ../libexec/pyenv-realpath.dylib realpath.o
thleo ~ thleo/.pyenv - (master) > ~  arch
arm64
thleo ~ thleo/.pyenv - (master) > ~  which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
thleo ~ thleo/.pyenv - (master) > ~  brew --version
Homebrew 3.5.4
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision e2e2cd1d5f0; last commit 2022-07-07)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 63bdf4e642; last commit 2022-07-07)
thleo ~ thleo/.pyenv - (master) > ~  vi ~/.zshrc
thleo ~ thleo/.pyenv - (master) > ~
```

#### Behavior after install:

*On launching new session in terminal:*

```bash
Last login: Fri Jul  8 16:18:29 on ttys005
/Users/thleo/.zshrc:61: command not found: pyenv
thleo ~ /Users/thleo  > ~  brew
zsh: command not found: brew
thleo ~ /Users/thleo  > ~  pyenv --version
pyenv 2.3.2-1-g207f33fc
```

### Question(s):

- why is `brew` not found? I can't seem to find folders related to homebrew anywhere on the machine [searched via finder]
- why is there a `command not found: pyenv` error when I can clearly use the command?

Comment: The basic problem here is the `$PATH` setting. zsh (and bash and other shells) use `$PATH` to find programs. You can *set* `$PATH` any time you like in your shell; the setting is generally passed down to sub-shells and programs that you run, and those use that setting, but they can't change the setting you've set in your shell (changes only go "downward", not "upward", as they're copied at process creation time). So, if you have `$PATH` set so that pyenv *can't* be found at line 61 of .zshrc, but then you *update* `$PATH` later so that *other* attempts to run `pyenv` *do* find it, [continued]

Comment: [cont'd] you get exactly what you're seeing here. It's therefore very important to set `$PATH` *at the right time*. In dot-files (.profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, .login, and other such files that various shells "source" at various points) it becomes very important to know *the exact order* in which the files are sourced, and under which conditions. You have to keep track of what may or may not be in `$PATH` at that point and whether you need to update it now.

Comment: `brew` normally lives in `/usr/local/bin` (when you *can* run it, run `which brew` to see this, or `type brew`, which is a bit different in bash, sh, and zsh each). So you'll need `/usr/local/bin` to be in `$PATH`. pyenv works by *altering* `$PATH`, and also `$PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I'm old-school (well, I'm old!) so I don't actually use zsh msyelf; I still use bash, and sometimes tcsh. So I'm not up on all the fine details about which files zsh sources at which points—but it is documented; see the zsh manual pages.

Comment: Last: Note that Git isn't involved here at all, other than the fact that you used Git to obtain these various bits of software. Had you downloaded them as zip files, the behavior would be the same.

Comment: Got it -- I updated the path to include all [the eval outputs] pyenv paths and brew path and it no longer had issues. I had thought this to be the underlying issue of python builds failing :\ guess I'll have to keep searching.